# How to connect and pull data out of funambol dm server using j2se client ?I

Tags: funambol, oma-dm

I have installed the DM server and it is up and running.Also added couple of device details via koneki simulator.

Now i want to use one of the j2se client to connect and pull data from DM server.

I am struck on this part.Any code sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there **is** an OMA-DM client underneath the Koneki simulator that you might want to reuse!

You can grab the source code from the GitHub mirrors of the OMA-DM simulator: [here](https://github.com/eclipse/koneki.protocols) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse/koneki.simulators)

- `org.eclipse.koneki.simulators.omadm` is used to run a new OMA-DM session. Look for the `run()` method in the class `org.eclipse.koneki.simulators.omadm.basic.DMBasicSimulation`
- `org.eclipse.koneki.protocols.omadm`  defines the object model used during a simulation.
- `org.eclipse.koneki.protocols.omadm.client`  (the most interesting for you) manages all the messages that are exchanged between a client (e.g. the simulator) and a server. Look for the `org.eclipse.koneki.protocols.omadm.client.basic.DMBasicSession` class.

You should stop by the [Koneki forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.koneki) if you have any further questions (and I am sure you will!)

Comment: How about accessing the ejb exposed by dm server ? I tried to access the exposed bean using initial context look up but i am getting the below error, com.funambol.framework.tools.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Resource com/funambol/server/store/PersistentStoreManager.xml not found with sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1372a1a

Comment: I have tried adding the PersistentStoreManager in the classpath